# How can I send a variable from a fragment to a view model in MVVM architecture in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Well I am a beginner with android and kotlin so I have been trying to send a variable **semesterSelected** from the fragment **ViewCourses** to my viewmodel **UserViewModel** is the codes are down below.

```
`class ViewCourses(path: String) : ReplaceFragment() {
    private var semesterSelected= path

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        container?.removeAllViews()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_courses, container, false)
    }



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        userRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        userRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = MyAdapter()
        userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        makeToast(semesterSelected)

//        The variable I am trying to send to UserViewModel is  -->> semesterSelected
        var viewModel: UserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

        viewModel.allUsers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

            adapter.updateUserList(it)

        }

    }
}
```

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: UserRepository = UserRepository("CSE/year3semester1").getInstance()
    private val _allUsers = MutableLiveData<List<CourseData>>()
    val allUsers: LiveData<List<CourseData>> = _allUsers


    init {

        repository.loadUsers(_allUsers)

    }

}
```

The reason I am doing this is I am wanting a to send a variable to my repository **UserRepository** all the way from **ViewCourses** and thought sending this via **UserViewModel** might be a way .

```
class UserRepository(semesterSelected: String) {
// The variable I am expecting to get from UserViewModel
    private var semesterSelected = semesterSelected
    private val databaseReference: DatabaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("course-list/$semesterSelected")

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: UserRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(): UserRepository {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {

            val instance = UserRepository(semesterSelected)
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }


    }


    fun loadUsers(userList: MutableLiveData<List<CourseData>>) {

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                try {

                    val courseList: List<CourseData> = snapshot.children.map { dataSnapshot ->

                        dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseData::class.java)!!

                    }

                    userList.postValue(courseList)

                } catch (e: Exception) {

                }


            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })


    }

}
```

I tried something like below

```
class ViewCourses(path: String) : ReplaceFragment() {
    private var semesterSelected= path

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        container?.removeAllViews()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_courses, container, false)
    }



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        userRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        userRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = MyAdapter()
        userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        makeToast(semesterSelected)
**// Sending the variable as parameter**
        var viewModel: UserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel(semesterSelected)::class.java]

        viewModel.allUsers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

            adapter.updateUserList(it)

        }

    }
}
```

```
class UserViewModel(semesterSelected: String) : ViewModel() {

    private val repository: UserRepository = UserRepository("CSE/year3semester1").getInstance()
    private val _allUsers = MutableLiveData<List<CourseData>>()
    val allUsers: LiveData<List<CourseData>> = _allUsers


    init {

        repository.loadUsers(_allUsers)

    }

}
```

but doing this my app crashes . how can this be done ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "but doing this my app crashes"... What is the crash?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.homepage.courseTab.Model.UserViewModel
 at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)

This is the starting of the crash report!

Comment: Is there a reason why it isn't able to create an instance when I am trying to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var viewModel: UserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel(semesterSelected)::class.java]
```

`UserViewModel(semesterSelected)::class.java` NOR `UserViewModel::class.java` is a constructor for the view model.

If you would want to have `ViewModel` with that **NEEDS** initial parameters, you will have to create your own factory for that - which is a tad more complicated and for your case, it might be overkill for what you are trying to do but in the longterm it will pay off([Getting started with VM factories](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories)).

With that said, your needs can be easily solved by one function to initialize the view model.

```
class UserViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var repository: UserRepository
    private val _allUsers = MutableLiveData<List<CourseData>>()
    val allUsers: LiveData<List<CourseData>> = _allUsers

    fun initialize(semesterSelected: String) {
        repository = UserRepository("CSE/year3semester1").getInstance()
        repository.loadUsers(_allUsers)
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a ton!  it solved my problem perfectly :). You are a savior.

Answer (score 2):

A ViewModel must be created using a ViewModelProvider.Factory. But there is a default Factory that is automatically used if you don't specify one. The default factory can create ViewModels who have constructor signatures that are one of the following:

1. empty, for example `MyViewModel: ViewModel`.
2. saved state handle, for example `MyViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel`
3. application, for example `MyViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application)`
4. both, for example `MyViewModel(application: Application, private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): AndroidViewModel(application)`

If your constructor doesn't match one of these four above, you must create a ViewModelProvider.Factory that can instantiate your ViewModel class and use that when specifying your ViewModelProvider. In Kotlin, you can use `by viewModels()` for easier syntax. All the instructions for how to create your ViewModelFactory [are here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I  solved the current problem using the solution given by [thelibrarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3434763/thelibrarian) which did my job. Looking forward to getting into the details.